# Core dumped in Assembly in collatz conjecture program

Tags: assembly

I want to implement Collatz conjecture in assembly. It's algorithm should count how many steps are required until the value of EAX becomes 1. But I have problem, when I'm trying to execute, console shows "Core Dumped" or it freezes. I store a count of steps in EBX. I call this function in main part of program by `push eax` `call f` `pop eax`.

```
f:
mov eax, [esp+4]
cmp eax,1
je end
AND eax, 0x01
jz parity
    inc ebx
    imul eax,3
    inc eax
parity:
    inc ebx
    shr eax,1
    jmp f
end:

mov eax,ebx

ret
```

Please help

**UPDATE**

Solved.

```
  f:
 mov eax, [esp+4]
 mov ebx, 1         ;In case EAX=1 !!!
jjump:
 cmp eax,1
 je end
 test eax, 0x01
 jz parity
 inc ebx
 imul eax,3
 inc eax
 jmp jjump
parity:
 inc ebx
 shr eax,1
 jmp jjump
end:
 mov eax,ebx
 ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written an endless loop. If the value at [esp+4] is anything else than 1 you always jump back to the label *f* and re-read the same value!

Put the label here:

```
f:
mov eax, [esp+4]
f_:
```

You should probably `test eax, 1` instead of `and` because the latter destroys the value you want to continu with.

Both possibilities must jump to the extra label *jjump*

```
 jmp  jjump
parity:
```

The whole code becomes:

```
f:
 mov eax, [esp+4]
 mov ebx, 1         ;In case EAX=1 !!!
jjump:
 cmp eax,1
 je end
 test eax, 0x01
 jz parity
 inc ebx
 imul eax,3
 inc eax
 jmp jjump
parity:
 inc ebx
 shr eax,1
 jmp jjump
end:
 mov eax,ebx
 ret
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I changed it. After mov eax, [esp+4] I added jump: and now It jumps there. But the program still freezes. I think I can't move label f: because It's my function which I call in main program by call f